# Is there a way to set Tabs content with json data loaded from my backend in reactjs using map() or forEach()?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, material-ui

I want to assign to each  tag the key of an object using a loop so that when I click on an item, I navigate to its content in the .
I tried using map() but I doubt this is the correct methodology as it doesn't work.
I'm starting with react. So any help will be really useful to me.

Here is the code! Thanks!

```
<Tabs
   orientation="vertical"
   variant="scrollable"
   value={value}
   onChange={handleChange}
   aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
   className={classes.tabs}
>
   apiData.map((data, i)=> {
      <Tab label=`Item ${i}` key={i} {...a11yProps(i)} />
   })

  </Tabs>
    apiData.map((data, i)=> return <TabPanel value={value} key={i} index={i}> data </TabPanel>
  })
```

Comment: what is `a11yProps`. Is it a function or an object? If its a function what are you returning.

Comment: You have missed `return` in the tab itterator. Here, ```apiData.map((data, i)=> {<Tab label=`Item ${i}` key={i} {...a11yProps(i)} />   })``` Change it to `{apiData.map((data, i) => { return <Tab label={data} {...a11yProps(i)} />;})}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use javascript code inside the JSX, you need to enclose that within `{ }`.

When you use `{ }` in the body of the arrow function you need to use `return` statement to return data. If you don't have `{ }` and have a one line statement, the oneline statement is returned.

```
<Tabs
    orientation="vertical"
    variant="scrollable"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
    className={classes.tabs}
>
    {apiData.map((data, i) => {
        return <Tab label={data} {...a11yProps(i)} />;
    })}
</Tabs>

{
    apiData.map((data, i) => {
        return (
            <TabPanel value={value} key={i} index={i}>
                {data}
            </TabPanel>
        );
    })
}
```